# Generic Deserialization of ContractData: returning a type of 'T' from the exception handler

Tags: c#, generics

I am probably violating a design pattern here, unintentionally. I'll mend my ways if you'll kindly explain what I'm doing wrong.

I want to write a generic json deserializer that returns an object of the supplied type:

```
public T DeserializeContractData<T>(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {

                var obj = (T)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(context.Request.InputStream);
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;   // ????
            }
        }
```

What should be returned from the exception block if the deserialization fails?

Comment: Bad practice to handle the exception this way. You should let the caller handle it.

Comment: Why would you need to write one yourself? Are you going to use this in production code? If so, I'd really suggest going with either Json.NET or ServiceStack's json deserializer

Comment: OK, I will let caller handle the exception. Thanks for the advice, @BlueM and EdgySwingsetAcid.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: I want to get a JSON object POSTed to a web handler (ashx). Is it possible to use Json.NET to extract the post-ed object from the httpContext?

Comment: @Tim Posted an answer, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i suggested, using Json.NET and not by trying to create your custom deserializer:

```
    public T DeserializeContractData<T>(HttpContext context) where T: new()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                var json = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            }
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException e)
        {
            //maybe do some logging...
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

I added a constraint on the T param so it has a default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

```
return default(T)
```

Not so short answer:

```
it depends :)
```

Depends on whether returning `default` value(null for classes, default instances for structures) is ok for you or not.

If it is acceptable, then I'd recommend to name you method like: `DeserializeContractDataOrDefault` - it will make things more obvious.

If it is not acceptable for you(I do agree with @BlueM that *in general* it's better to allow the caller to handle the error) - then it's better to:

- to not handle the exception, let the caller to deal with it ;
- handle the exception(optionally, log it) re-throw it;
- handle the exception(optionally, log it) re-throw the new one with more verbose
  explanation and original one s inner;

And one more approach I could suggest would be  to add some smart logic for providing fallback value. Something like:

```
public T DeserializeContractData<T>(HttpContext context, Func<HttpContext, T> getFallbackValue = null)
        {
            try
            {

                var obj = (T)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(context.Request.InputStream);
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(getFallbackValue == null)
                {
                     throw;
                }

                return getFallbackValue(context);
            }
        }
```

Caller is able to provide any logic via `getFallbackValue`, hence use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything else you want to do in an exception case (logging, etc)?  If not, you could just use the *as* keyword (using @aleksey.berezan's default(T) suggestion):

```
public static T DeserializeContractData<T>(HttpContext context)
{
    var obj = new DataContractionJsonSerializer(typeof(T))
                  .ReadObject(context.Request.InputStream)
              as T;

    return obj ?? default(T);
}
```

Alternatively, just remove the exception-handling from that method and have whatever uses it do that.  Generally, I try not to use exceptions unless there's an explicit reason for using the exception ... well, unless it's best to swallow up the exception.  Generally I don't like them for "catch-all" situations.